# Grub Rescue Dualboot Problem Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, bios

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a dualboot with Windows 10(Dell Latitude E6430)

During the installation process I chose ubuntu's `Install Alongside Windows` option.

Both OS are installed in legacy mode.

After restarting my PC and chose Windows in GRUB, it had a BSOD:

`SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION`

after it rebooted and only showed the grub rescue mode (grub did not show up).

How can I fix the Windows Bootloader and Grub? Should I use the Boot Repair in Live Ubuntu or something else?  I don't want a risky method because I do not want to sacrifice my data. Thanks a lot for every response!
**Also I am a Linux noob**

Comment: Use Boot-repair on Ubuntu live CD

Comment: Thank you, also after that can i change  the bootloader from GRUB to the Windows one via EasyBCD?

Comment: That I never tried.

Comment: Okay,still thank you very much because i got into the Windows Bootloader, if there is any problem i will post here.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, so Windows 10 , after it did it's stuff is fine, well Ubuntu not so much. It doesn't boot to grub at all and when i checked on GParted the partition is completely unallocated. Might this be a problem of my iso/usb or it just had a bad install? Can i retry the installation a few days later?

Comment: If your windows not booting  you can still use Boot-repair(even if your Ubuntu installation is bad/ corrupt). It can help you to repair at least Windows to boot. You can re-install Ubuntu later on. just follow instructions of boot repair and don't forget to save pastebin copy.

Comment: Hi, i did that but now i want to install ubuntu again ,sadly i didn't save  a pastebin copy but im going to use the second option of boot repair, do i need to do anything before retrying my ubuntu install or just the same options again? PASTEBIN COPY:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3wbzkpnfZm/