# I installed Ubuntu,now it's completly unallocated

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual-boot with Windows and when it rebooted i chose Windows instead of Ubuntu . Windows had a BSOD: `SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION` and I manually powered it off. When i booted it went into grub rescue mode.

I ran BOOT-Repair and then after i rebooted , it rebooted to Windows(probably overwrited my MBR). Windows is working but there is no GRUB.
I checked Disk Managment and a other partitioning tool on Windows and also GPARTED in Ubuntu USB and the ext4 partiton is completely unallocated.
I used a MBR usb flashed by  Rufus and  installed both OS-es in legacy(Windows 10 came with Legacy and MBR).

Dell Latitude E6430 (Used Install Ubuntu alongide Winddows 10 option)
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3wbzkpnfZm/ (Boot Repair Log)
[Grub Rescue Dualboot Problem Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242553/grub-rescue-dualboot-problem-ubuntu-20-04) (First Post More details there)

Can i extend my C: drive then install Ubuntu again? Is Ubuntu or Grub still intact? Also the first question gives some more details. Thank you !

Comment: Also in the boot-repair results i saw something about Windows not being completely shut down, as a noob and idiot i forgot to share boot repair results, should i do a boot repair scan(second option) and share it to you?

Comment: Why did you run boot repair?

Comment: Because after the BSOD it was in Grub Rescue, it had no bootpicker

Comment: That fixed windows but not ubuntu

Comment: There is no BSOD in your question. We can't read your mind.

Comment: So sorry about that here is my first post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242553/grub-rescue-dualboot-problem-ubuntu-20-04 that has some more details.

Comment: You should edit your question (not comment) and explain that there is a related question with more information, and include a link to the other question.

Comment: ok so i did that

Comment: Can i extend the space of the unallocated space on the ubuntu partiton after deleting it in GPARTED?