# Ubuntu Installer does not recognize partitions but GPARTED does

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu(dualboot), it had problems and entered into grub rescue mode, fixed that with boot repair, but that fixed only windows bootloader.

In GPARTED i get : `invalid partition table on dev/sda - wrong signature ffff"`. Ubuntu Installer does not recognize the partition table, GPARTED does. Under ubuntu partition its completely unallocated stuff. In the installer, there is no "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option despite Windows being completely shut down , both in the same mode.

Also i saw GRUB one time when ubuntu was rebooting after install , and i chose Windows(bad decision).

Windows Boots,legacy and MBR both OS-es, Windows was installed first.

Can i just delete the Ubuntu Partition because GRUB is broken and so is Ubuntu because it is completly unallocated?

Now the boot repair log is in this post and also more details: [I installed Ubuntu,now it's completly unallocated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242726/i-installed-ubuntu-now-its-completly-unallocated?noredirect=1#comment2094334_1242726)

Also i included a screenshot of GPARTED, hope that helps.[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlWnt.png)

Comment: You show a 1.1T partition sda5 on your 120GB drive. It says error will be corrected with a write. So do a write. `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` and then press w to do the write. Always best to have good backups for any system change as things do go awry. Make sure Windows fast start up is off. Use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition to make room for / (root) and either create / during install or use gparted to create in advance & use Something else to select that partition as ext4 & as / .

Comment: Bios has its limitations. For example it can't have more than 4 primary partitions. If your device support UEFI, you are much more better off installing the OS as UEFI. You can convert windows to UEFI from mbr2gpt utility. I will give more instructions if you need them.

Comment: yeah my laptop supports uefi, i'll probably do that